# Manipulating pandas dataframe with unnamed columns and use the values of these columns to convert into rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm very new to learning python and hence i need help to manipulate the below dataframe:

```
name    location    commodity   service carrier agent   date                                
sometext    sometext    sometext    sometext    sometext    sometext    sometext    L1              L2_abc          
sometext    sometext    sometext    sometext    sometext    sometext    sometext    total_amount_min    total_amount    total_amount_type   total_amount_curr   total1_amount_min   total1_amount   total1_amount_type  total1_amount_curr
xyz bangalore   aa  xyz pol cvb 12-12-2020  nan 10  cbm INR nan 10  fgh INR
xyz bangalore   aa  xyz pol cvb 12-12-2021  nan 10  cbm INR 4   15  fgh INR
abc mumbai  bb  xyz pol cvb 12-12-2023  5   10  cbm INR nan 10  fgh INR
abc mumbai  bb  xyz pol cvb 12-12-2024  nan 5   cbm INR nan 10  fgh INR
pqr goa cc  xyz pol cvb 12-12-2026  nan 5   cbm INR nan 3   fgh INR
pqr goa cc  xyz pol cvb 12-12-2027  nan 3   cbm INR nan 4   fgh INR
```

to get the output dataframe as:

```
name    location    commodity   service carrier agent   date    charges type    amount  amount_min  level   currency
xyz bangalore   aa  xyz pol cvb 12-12-2020  total_amount    cbm 10  nan L1  INR
xyz bangalore   aa  xyz pol cvb 12-12-2021  total_amount    cbm 10  nan L1  INR
abc mumbai  bb  xyz pol cvb 12-12-2023  total_amount    cbm 10  5   L1  INR
abc mumbai  bb  xyz pol cvb 12-12-2024  total_amount    cbm 5   nan L1  INR
pqr goa cc  xyz pol cvb 12-12-2026  total_amount    cbm 5   nan L1  INR
pqr goa cc  xyz pol cvb 12-12-2027  total_amount    cbm 3   nan L1  INR
xyz bangalore   aa  xyz pol cvb 12-12-2020  total1_amount   fgh 10  nan L2_abc  INR
xyz bangalore   aa  xyz pol cvb 12-12-2021  total1_amount   fgh 15  4   L2_abc  INR
abc mumbai  bb  xyz pol cvb 12-12-2023  total1_amount   fgh 10  nan L2_abc  INR
abc mumbai  bb  xyz pol cvb 12-12-2024  total1_amount   fgh 10  nan L2_abc  INR
pqr goa cc  xyz pol cvb 12-12-2026  total1_amount   fgh 3   nan L2_abc  INR
pqr goa cc  xyz pol cvb 12-12-2027  total1_amount   fgh 4   nan L2_abc  INR
```

Note: the dtype of all the columns is object.

---

What Prachi has tried:

```
first_row = charges.iloc[0].values.tolist()
charge_leg = []
for i, row_value in enumerate(first_row):
    if str(row_value).startswith('L'):
        charge_leg.append(i)
```

Comment: Sorry mate but I cannot get what you wanna get, could you please clarify a little bit?

Comment: I appreciate you are new to python, but what have you tried? Where are you stuck? This isn't really even a question and against StackOverflow rules, because you are just saying I have this data, and I want this data, but there isn't an actual question or attempt to solve. Also, the title of the question is "Manipulating pandas dataframe to get the desired output" which describes 90%+ of StackOverflow  `pandas` questions and is not unique.

Comment: @DavidErickson I'm sorry but i dont know how to go about it. i have some unnamed columns with the column values L1 and L2_cha. what i want to do is get the values of these columns in rows. i tried using a loop to get the indexes but i dont know what to do further.
`first_row = charges.iloc[0].values.tolist()

                    charge_leg = []
                    for i, row_value in enumerate(first_row):
                        if str(row_value).startswith('L'):
                            charge_leg.append(i)`

Comment: @Prachi it's better to post what you have attempted formatted in the question rather than a comment. Also, based off the code you have tried, think how you can update the title of the question, which dictates it's value in the future when people try to google how to solve a similar problem. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidErickson yes, i have edited the comment.

Comment: @Prachi but you should put that in the question not as a comment.

Comment: @Prachi, if it is a `pandas` dataframe, and you want to sort it by the `Level` column, you have to do something like: `df.sort_values(by=['Level'])` where `df` is your dataframe name. Could you explain better what you want in the post?